# Text file to excel file C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I can export to this excel over two different text files on this code.
The code writes data to two different cells.
But what I want is to split a text file.
as below example:
Over a text file
example1 10
example1 20
example1 30
[What I want the program to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg5pB.png)
transfer to excel in this way
What I want is to split the list and transfer it to two different values

```
string[] InputNamesLine = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/test/test.txt");
            string[] InputLinksLine = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/test/test1.txt");


            excel.Application oXL;
                excel._Workbook oWB;
                excel._Worksheet oSheet;
                excel.Range oRng;
                object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            try
            {
                //start excel and get application object
                oXL = new excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = true;
                //Create new workbook
                oWB = (excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
                oSheet = (excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
                //Add table headers going cell
                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Parameter_Names";
                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Values";
                //Format A1:B1 as bold and vertical alignment=center
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").VerticalAlignment = excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

                for (int i = 1; i < InputNamesLine.Length; i = i + 2)
                {
                    //oSheet.Cells[1][i + 1] = i;
                    oSheet.Cells[1][i + 2] = InputNamesLine[i];
                    oSheet.Cells[2][i + 2] = InputLinksLine[i];
                }
                for (int a = 0; a <= InputNamesLine.Length; a = a+2)
                {
                    //oSheet.Cells[1][i + 1] = i;
                    oSheet.Cells[1][a+2] = InputNamesLine[a];
                    oSheet.Cells[2][a+2] = InputLinksLine[a];
                }
                //for (int a = 1; a <= InputNamesLine.Length; a = a + 2)
                //{
                //    //oSheet.Cells[1][i + 1] = i;
                //    oSheet.Cells[1][a + 2] = InputNamesLine[a];
                //    oSheet.Cells[2][a + 2] = InputLinksLine[a];
                //}
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1");
                //oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                oWB.SaveAs(@"C:\test\texts1.xlsx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                oWB.Close();
                oXL.Quit();
            }
```

Comment: what happens when you run your code.. whats the issue that you need help with

Comment: Code writes content in text files to excel cells.
The code reads the text file, passes it to value and then writes it to the excel cell

Comment: But is it working as expected? If not, why is not working as expected?

Comment: What library are you using? Why do you set the headers like this `oSheet.Cells[1, 1]` but fill your data like this `oSheet.Cells[1][i + 2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution of the code is below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++)
{
    foreach (string line in InputNamesLine)
                     {
                        if (line != "")
                        {
                            string[] columns = line.Split(' ');
                            string column1 = columns[0];
                            string column2 = columns[1];
                            //oSheet.Cells[1][i + 1] = i;
                            oSheet.Cells[1][i + 2] = column1;
                            oSheet.Cells[2][i + 2] = column2;
                            i = i+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```